# python bottle route with regex not matching - 404 error

Tags: javascript, python, regex, routes, bottle

I'm trying to setup a python camera app that streams to a browser and am using bottle.  My javascript in the index.html is this:

```
<div class="panel-body"> <img src="stream/d" onload="imageRefresh(this, 30);" style="max-width: 100%;">
```

The imageRefresh function uses setTimeout and it takes the image url and appends a time value to it so that it is unique and the browser will fire off a request to the server.  This process worked fine with a server I found on the internet called microwebsrv which is on github at:
https://github.com/jczic/MicroWebSrv; however, I'm trying to move over to bottle on my raspberry pi.
My routes for bottle look like this:

```
@route('/stream/d')
@route('/stream/<val:re:d[\d]+>')
def _httpStream(val="d")
  print("val: %s" % val)
  (rest of code here)
```

However, after the very first image is served (I see the image flash on the browser screen and in on the developer console I see http://192.168.0.18:8080/stream/d; I also see the "GET /stream/d" on the rPi terminal from which I launched the app) then the next get request which looks like:
http://192.168.0.18:8080/stream/d1633472974918
fails with a 404 error, I presume because the route isn't matching?  I have also tried by simply using a route like: @route(/stream/) but I still get the same error.
The imageRefresh function updates the img.src like this:

```
img.src=http + '/d' + d.getTime();
```

I've read the bottle docs a number of times and I've tested my regex with a "regex Regular Expression Tool" I installed from the Windows store.  The regex tool shows it matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!  Firstly, I put this particular route first in the program.
Then, I changed the routes to be:

```
    @app.route('/stream/<time>')
    
    @app.route('/stream/<time:re:d.*>')
```

This took care of the 404 problem and now I'm able to stream images captured from a camera.
Thanks for the suggestions above, I also upgraded to 0.13-dev and changed my simplified my regex.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that you have specified two routes but only one specifies variable name `val` and this is an inconsistency. I am no expert in `Bottle`, but you might try the following:

```py
@route('/stream/<val:re:d[\d]*>')
def _httpStream(val="d")
  print("val: %s" % val)
  (rest of code here)
```

This now allows 0 or more digits after the 'd'.

By the way, your regex could also have been more simply specified as `d\d*`.

**Update**

I created the following simple program ...

```py
from bottle import route, run

@route('/stream/<val:re:d[\d]*>')
def hello(val):
    return val

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

... and everything worked as expected. I should add that specifying two routes with a default value for argument `val` also works:

```py
from bottle import route, run

@route('/stream/d>')
@route('/stream/<val:re:d[\d]+>')
def hello(val="d"):
    return val

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: I changed it as suggest and even the first camera shot doesn't work - in other words it doesn't match on stream/d and that's with the re:d\d* as you suggested.  It's very frustrating since it seems as if it should work, but it doesn't.  That's why I had the first route in there with just 'stream/d' before; at least that way, I got a flash of image until it got to sending the second video frame resulting in a 404.

Comment: And you are running the latest version of bottle?

Comment: I believe so, Bottle v0.12.19 which is what pip install bottle installed.

Comment: I downloaded v0.13-dev bottle.py and put it in my project directory, no bottle in my python environment and still doesn't work.  If I use @route('/stream/<val:re:d\d*>'), it won't even match the "http://192.168.0.18:8080/stream/d" which is what the very first image source would be.  If I add the @route('/stream/d') I will get the first image but will never match on any image source that has something like:
"http://192.168.0.18:8080/stream/d1234567654321" - 404 error! The last case I have:
```
    @route('/stream/d')
    @route('/stream/<val:re:d\d*>')
```

Comment: And, of course, using `d\d*` as the regex works, too.